# how to remove element from array when it is unchecked from checkbox?

Tags: android, arraylist

hello all i want to remove element when checkbox is unchecked in itemonsetchenge listner.
here is my code

```
  checkbox_timeslot.clear();

          chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String chetimeslot;

                if(isChecked){          

                chetimeslot = (String)chk.getTag();
                checkbox_timeslot.add(chetimeslot);             
                Log.e("array value", ""+checkbox_timeslot);             
                Log.e("checked slo value", ""+chetimeslot);

                }else{          

                checkbox_timeslot.add("");
                Log.e("else array value", ""+checkbox_timeslot);    

            }        
        }

        });
```

"checkbox_timeslot" is my string array list.i want to remove the element in checkbox is unchecked and add item when checked from list of checkbox..how is it possible help??

Comment: yes,solved it.hey can you plz tell me how can i count how much checkbox user have checked??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(isChecked){          

    chetimeslot = (String)chk.getTag();
    checkbox_timeslot.add(chetimeslot);             
    Log.e("array value", ""+checkbox_timeslot);             
    Log.e("checked slo value", ""+chetimeslot);

} else{          

     chetimeslot = (String)chk.getTag();
     checkbox_timeslot.remove(chetimeslot);
     Log.e("else array value", ""+checkbox_timeslot);    

}
```

Comment: @GooGLE ok i forget to set tag again to remove element in arraylist. Great work dude.

Comment: hey can you plz tell me how can i count how much checkbox user have checked??

Comment: Yes you create one int variable count=0; now put count++ in if(isChecked){ count++} else count--

Comment: most welcome dude.. and i update my answer you can accept it if you like.

Comment: I am using this code and getting error and my app crashed can someone please help me how can i use this code i want the same scenerio

Comment: Ask your question and give me a link.

Answer (score 0):

use add(item) to add an element to array list. remove(item) to remove from the list.

```
chetimeslot = (String)chk.getTag();
if(isChecked){

    checkbox_timeslot.add(chetimeslot);

} else{          

    checkbox_timeslot.remove(chetimeslot);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(isChecked){

           chetimeslot = (String)chk.getTag();
           checkbox_timeslot.add(chetimeslot);

        }else{

          chetimeslot = (String)chk.getTag();
          checkbox_timeslot.remove(chetimeslot);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i have got today. This is how i have solved it. 
I'm posting my whole adapter class using RecyclerView.

```
package com.aqua.machinetest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Danish.sharma on 5/9/2017.
 */

public class GovernateListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GovernateListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Governate> governateList;
    public static ArrayList<String> arrayListSelectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public GovernateListAdapter(List<Governate> governateList, Context context) {
        this.governateList = governateList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.governate_list_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Governate governate = governateList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(governate.getName());

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(governateList.get(position).getCheckedBox());
        holder.checkBox.setTag(governateList.get(position));

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                Governate governate1 = (Governate) cb.getTag();

                governate1.setCheckedBox(cb.isChecked());
                governateList.get(position).setCheckedBox(cb.isChecked());
                System.out.println("selected contacts list " + governate1.getId());

                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), contact.getName() + " is " + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    arrayListSelectedContacts.add(governateList.get(position).getId());
                } else {
                    arrayListSelectedContacts.remove(governateList.get(position).getId());
                }

                System.out.println("selected contacts list 3 " + arrayListSelectedContacts);
                Toast.makeText(context, arrayListSelectedContacts.size() + " Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return governateList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public CheckBox checkBox;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Title);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my pojo class:

```
package com.aqua.machinetest;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Danish.sharma on 5/9/2017.
 */

public class Governate  {
    String id;
    String name;
    Boolean checkedBox = false;
 //   List<Governate> governateList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Governate() {

    }

    public Governate(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
       // this.governateList = governateList;
    }

    protected Governate(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
    }



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getCheckedBox() {
        return checkedBox;
    }

    public void setCheckedBox(Boolean checkedBox) {
        this.checkedBox = checkedBox;
    }


}
```

At Last: This my Fragment where i'm implementing onClickListener

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.linear_Next:
            try {
                if (GovernateListAdapter.arrayListSelectedContacts.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No data selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (GovernateListAdapter.arrayListSelectedContacts.size() > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected data=" + GovernateListAdapter.arrayListSelectedContacts.size(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```